# Angular Jasmine Unit Testing: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $confirmProvider

Tags: jasmine

Hello I am writing my first angular test with Jasmine but I keep getting the error,i'm test controller y confirm not run test , i'm inject confirm in controller:  Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: **$confirmProvider** my code is:

my Spec

```
describe('Controller : diagramaController', function () {
    var scope, rootScope, controller, $confirm, UserCtrl;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('Mycontrollers');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$confirm_, $routeParams) {
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $confirm = _$confirm_;
        UserCtrl = $controller('diagramaController', { $scope: scope, $confirm: confirm });
    }));

    it('Deberia agregar  y sumar uno', function () {
        //var $scope = {};
        //var controller = $controller('actividadController', { $scope: $scope });
        var contador = 0;
        expect(contadoractual).toBe(contadorGenerado - 1);
    });
});
```

my controller:

```
    (function () {
    angular.module('Mycontrollers', [])
    .controller('diagramaController',['$scope', '$http', '$confirm', '$filter', '$timeout', '$routeParams', '$modal', '$rootScope',
        function ($scope, $http, $confirm, $filter, $timeout, $routeParams,$modal, $rootScope)
     {
      $scope.contador = 1;
      })();
```

my app here inject confirmar:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [
        'angucomplete-alt',
        'ngDraggable',
         'Mycontrollers',
         'ngRoute',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'Confirmar'
    ])
  })();

};
```

confirmar js

```
angular.module("Confirmar", [])
.controller('ConfirmModalController', function ($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
    $scope.data = angular.copy(data);
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
})
.value('$confirmModalDefaults', {
    template: '<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title">Confirmar</h3></div><div class="modal-body">{{data.text}}</div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Aceptar</button><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancelar</button></div>',
    controller: 'ConfirmModalController'
})
.factory('$confirm', function ($modal, $confirmModalDefaults) {
    return function (data, settings) {
        settings = angular.extend($confirmModalDefaults, (settings || {}));
        data = data || {};

        if ('templateUrl' in settings && 'template' in settings) {
            delete settings.template;
        }
        settings.resolve = { data: function () { return data; } };
        return $modal.open(settings).result;
    };
})
```

Comment: can you also post here the code for `diagramaController` that you are trying to mock in the test? It would be good do have a plunkr with the code and failing test.

Comment: hi, the code is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/qqtI6BH5HYMk7ki5Xs0I, thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize all custom modules together with the module you will test:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module('Mycontrollers');
    module('Confirmar');
    module('myApp');
});
```

Edit:
[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oeWUlGDtA1NbpkPeNunr?p=preview) is a simplified version of your plunkr that works.  You have a few issues there. The first thing, you try to use $confirm which is not a standard angularjs directive, but has to be added separately, which means you have to inject it into your module, not only in your controller.

This is how it can be done:

1) add to your source code two dependencies:

```
<script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-confirm.js"></script>
```

You need ui-bootstrap because it is a dependency for angular-confirm directive.

These can be downloaded [here](http://schlogen.github.io/angular-confirm/) and [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

2) inject into module
     angular.module('MyControllers', ['angular-confirm'])
    .controller('diagramaController', ['$scope','$confirm',
        function ($scope, $confirm) {

Comment: don't work , the code is here: plnkr.co/edit/qqtI6BH5HYMk7ki5Xs0I

Comment: check my plunkr example and explanation

Comment: Thanks to replicate Diana R, I'll keep practicing angularjs testing. but then in my controler jsplumb use and do not have it in directive if not instantiated, it necessarily has to go in a policy? controller {   $scope.instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({....}

Comment: Never used jsPlumb, check for demos of its usages.